# How do I adjust the font sizes for iPad in iOS? (Clashing elements)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

I'm having problems with app elements clashing together on the smaller iPad size. Is there a way to resize the fonts so they're not so large in iPad? Samples below:

**App Screen on iPhone:**

[image]

**App Screen on iPad:**

[image]

Comment: Make app as Universal, Project ->  Project name (in Targets) -> Deployment Info -> Devices -> choose universal

Comment: From screenshot, your app is not made for iPad, it's for iPhones only, if you want your app to be work in both the follow as commented by @JaleelNazir and apply solution as answered by Vikash kumar

Answer (score 0):

Select your label in your storyboard. In the attributes inspector you will see a small '+' to the left of the font selector. This will allow you to choose size-class specific stuff for your text.
[image]

Size classes were added to iOS 8 when Apple introduced Universal Storyboards which let you design for both iPad and iPhone with the same Storyboard file. At the bottom of the Storyboard design window you'll see the (default) 'w Any h Any' button. This gives you access to combinations of the compact and regular size classes. These available combinations let you implement design, say for only the iPhone in landscape, or maybe the iPad in both orientations. You have full control.

For your font related question, you access the size-class control through the '+' sign I mentioned above.

This is a good explanation and tutorial: [Wenderlich size classes](http://www.raywenderlich.com/83276/beginning-adaptive-layout-tutorial)

and in Apple's explanation: [Apple size classes](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/overview/themes/http://)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Storyboard, then use auto layout properly to avoid overlapping in smaller screen sizes. Firstly, you should give minimum distance between each element. 
Secondly, for LABELS, there is a property `Autoshrink` in `Attributes Inspector` which when set to `Minimum Font Size` gives the ability to shrink the text size with the screen size accordingly.
For Text Field's, there is a property `Min Font Size` in `Attributes Inspector` which helps  shrink font sizes accordingly.
This can work in conjunction with the answer of @Vikash Kumar